# Not able to validate password inside views.py django

Tags: django

I have my own HTML form and I am using AbstractUser to create my own model, the problem that I am facing is when I try to register a new user I need to check whether the password and confirm password field matches. If it does not match, then I need to throw an error message. I have written this below logic in "views.py", the problem is even if the password does not match a new user is getting created in the backend. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
def registerPage(request):
    #form = UserCreationForm()
    user = User()
    if request.method == "POST":
        user.first_name = request.POST.get('txtFName')
        user.last_name = request.POST.get('txtFName')
        user.username = request.POST.get('txtUserName').lower()
        user.email = request.POST.get('txtEmail').lower()
        password1 = request.POST.get('txtPassword')
        password2 = request.POST.get('txtConfPassword')

        if password1 == password2:
             user.set_password(password2)
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Password and Confirm password do not match. Try again")

        user.is_superuser = False
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('home')

    return render(request,'login_register.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only save an diredirect if that is succesful, otherwise you construct a user with a "null" password:

```
def registerPage(request):
    # form = UserCreationForm()
    user = User()
    if request.method == "POST":
        user.first_name = request.POST.get('txtFName')
        user.last_name = request.POST.get('txtFName')
        user.username = request.POST.get('txtUserName').lower()
        user.email = request.POST.get('txtEmail').lower()
        password1 = request.POST.get('txtPassword')
        password2 = request.POST.get('txtConfPassword')

        if password1 == password2:
            user.set_password(password2)
            user.is_superuser = False
            user.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(
                request, "Password and Confirm password do not match. Try again"
            )

    return render(request, 'login_register.html')
```

---

> **Note**: It is better to use a [**`Form`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/)
> than to perform manual validation and cleaning of the data. A `Form` will not
> only simplify *rendering* a form in HTML, but it also makes it more convenient
> to *validate* the input, and *clean* the data to a more convenient type.